# How stable is the current version of Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, web, responsive

I'm wondering how stable the current version is for Flutter Web?

It looks like the authentications works well. But what about the Real-Time database & Firestore? Are you able to use these in the latest release? I would like to know if the current version works well with:

- SVG's
- Responsive enough?
- Firestore possible?
- Real-Time database supported? And do they use the same packages as the mobile version?
- Multiple browsers compatible
- Functions, are there CORS policy issues?
- Uploading files

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use firestore, just like you would with apps. But as far as overall stability of web, I would say its not fully stable or else it wouldn't be in the "stable" channel instead of "beta".

It is capable of doing most of the things that you can do on a mobile device within the app. The things that aren't fully stable yet are the web specific things. It is already responsive, and firestore and real time database work fine. It should be compatible on all browsers (but i haven't test that). I'm not sure what you mean by uploading files, but if you mean to some database then that should be no problem either.

I think for now, if you're just trying to set up a simple website it should be good enough for that, but if you want to do something more complex, I would wait until it is in the "stable" channel.